# Need help jQuery parsing an XML document and outputting HTML

Tags: jquery, xml, xml-parsing

I've seen a few examples of similar situations on here, but haven't found anything with my specific problem & I just can't seem to get it. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "linwood.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parseXml
    });
    function parseXml(xml){
        $(xml).find("loaction1").each(function(){
            if($(this).find("Available").text() == 'Yes'){
                $("#location1").append("<li><p><u><h4>Unit " + $(this).find("Unit").text() + " [" + $(this).find("Price").text() + "]:</h4></u>" + $(this).find("Description").text() + "<div class='small'>");
                $(this).find("Href").each(function(){
                    $("#location1").append("<a href='" + $(this).text() + "' rel='lightbox' ><img width='45px' height='35px' src='" + $(this).text() + "' /></a>");
                });
                $("#location1").append("</div></p></li>");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Basically what I am trying to do is produce list items (li) for the ul with the id 'location1'. So far what I have is the first line displaying properly. However I have learned that .append closes all open tags. This wouldn't be a problem, but for:

```
$(this).find("Href").each(function(){
```

I need the href the xml gives for each 'a' tag. I am thinking of adding them into an array and include that array in part of the '.append' section, but each li has a different number of links and I am not quite sure how make them read in then display properly. The end result HTML should look something like this:

```
<ul id="location1">
<li>
    <p>
       <u><h4>Unit 1 [$600]</h4><u>
       This unit is available for purchase
       <div class='small'>
           <a href='#' rel='lightbox'><img src='#' /></a>
           <a href='#' rel='lightbox'><img src='#' /></a>
           <a href='#' rel='lightbox'><img src='#' /></a>
       </div>
    </>
</li>
<li>
    <p>
       <u><h4>Unit 2 [$400]</h4><u>
       This unit is available for purchase
       <div class='small'>
           <a href='#' rel='lightbox'><img src='#' /></a>
       </div>
    </>
</li>
</ul>
```

Does anyone think they can help me out? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the main part to be:

```
var container = $("<li><p><u><h4>Unit " + $(this).find("Unit").text() + " [" + $(this).find("Price").text() + "]:</h4></u>" + $(this).find("Description").text() + "<div class='small'>")
$(this).find("Href").each(function(){
    container.append("<a href='" + $(this).text() + "' rel='lightbox' ><img width='45px' height='35px' src='" + $(this).text() + "' /></a>");
});
$("#location1").append(container);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked perfectly. Now that I see it laid out like that its kind of obvious, but that's why a fresh pair of eyes is always a best!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I can see being possible for you.  You can either write all the HTML necessary to a single variable, and then append that variable to the #location1 field, or you can maybe do:

```
$("#location1").html($("#location1").html()+"HTML here");
```

Obviously, the first option is probably the best solution (I don't know, off the top of my head, if html() also closes tags automatically).

If you need a more thorough explanation of what I mean (through code), I can supply it.  Just comment on my response.

Comment: You and Variant gave the same answer and it worked so thanks very much. This made today much better.

Comment: Glad I could help :-).  I posted first though, haha.